# Are there any Generative Adversarial Networks without Multi Layer Perceptrons?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks

Although the main stream research is on Generative Adversarial Networks(GANs) using Multi Layer Percepteons (MLPs). The original paper titled [Generative Adversarial Nets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf) clealry says, in abstract, that GAN is possible with out MLP also

> In the **space of arbitrary functions** $G$ and $D$, a unique solution
> exists, with $G$ recovering the training data distribution and $D$
> equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$ everywhere. In the case where G and D are defined
> by multilayer perceptrons, the entire system can be trained with backpropagation.

Are there any research papers that uses models other than MLPs and are comparatively successful?

Comment: [FCC-GAN: A Fully Connected and Convolutional Net
Architecture for GANs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.02417.pdf)

Comment: @Yahya It is also using MLP right?

Comment: I mix of two, but mainly a Convolution NN, look page 4, Table 1, the right column, for the architecture.

Comment: @Yahya Oh! In the question, i used MLP as a representative term for all forms of neural networks.

Comment: So Do you mean a non-ANN based model, such as a SVM or a simple Linear Model?

Comment: @Yahya yes exactly.

Comment: [Semi-supervised Generative Adversarial Networks Based on Scalable Support Vector Machines and Manifold Regularization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9164865). Here the discriminator uses SVM classifier.

Comment: @Yahya Feel free to provide a formal answer below (as comments are temporary), if you have an answer to this question ;)

Comment: Someone suggested to me to try using a Java compiler as a discriminator (to generate Java code), but I had to point out it wasn't differentiable and couldn't be weakened for training.